# Protobuf android : Migration to AndroidX : cannot find symbol class EnumVerifier

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers, androidx

I am migrating existing project to AndroidX.

When I try to run the app, I am getting "error: cannot find symbol class EnumVerifier" from "com.google.protobuf.Internal.java".
So I checked in auto generated file "Internal.java" and "EnumVerifier" is missing there.

Following is my gradle setup :

```
protobuf {
protoc {
artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.8.0'
}
generateProtoTasks {
all().each { task ->
task.builtins {
java {
option "lite"
}}}}}

dependancy {
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.8.0'
}

//Android level gradle
dependancy {
classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.10'
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this `build.gradle` has spelling errors, which corrupt it - and there is absolutely no relation to `androidx`.

Comment: Can you please mention what spelling errors?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and in my case the problem was the "lite" version, I replaced: `implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.25.0'` for: `implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.25.0'` and it compiles and deploys alright.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because I was using protobuf-lite (last updated in 2016) instead of protobuf-javalite. Not everyone wants/ needs **grpc** dependencies (Andres answer).

Use this:

```
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.13.0'
```